# c# API getting VM name from MOR

Tags: c#, vmware, vsphere, esxi

I am able to get a list of VM's MOR but is there a way to translate that to the actual VM names?
I used the PropertySpec with Traversalspec to get the MOR of the VM's but how do I convert that to the actual names.
I have for example 'VirtualMachine-15'.  I cannot find a way to get the name.

I'm using the vmware.vim.dll.

Below is part of the code to get the MOR of the VM's:

```
 ObjectContent[] objs = pCollector.RetrieveProperties(pFss);

        for (int i = 0; i < objs.Length; i++)
        {


            DynamicProperty[] dps = objs[i].PropSet;

            foreach (DynamicProperty d in dps)
            {

                if (d.Name == "childEntity")
                {
                    ManagedObjectReference[] vmMORs = (ManagedObjectReference[])d.Val;

                    foreach(ManagedObjectReference vmMOR in vmMORs )
                        {

                        listview1.Items.Add(vmMOR);

                        }
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I just had a similar problem that I worked out after a day of trial & error:

```
VimClientImpl client = new VimClientImpl();
client.Login(vSphereURI, loginID, loginPW);
List<EntityViewBase> vmlist = client.FindEntityViews(typeof(VirtualMachine), null, filter1, null);
List<EntityViewBase> hostlist = client.FindEntityViews(typeof(HostSystem), null, null, null);

foreach (HostSystem host in hostlist)
{
   host.UpdateViewData();
   Console.WriteLine(@"# Host: " + host.Name + @": ");

   for (int i = 0; i < host.Vm.Length; i++)
   {
      VirtualMachine vm = (VirtualMachine)client.GetView(host.Vm[i], null);
      Console.WriteLine(vm.Name);
   }
}

foreach (VirtualMachine vm in vmlist)
{
   vm.UpdateViewData();
   HostSystem host = (HostSystem)client.GetView(vm.Runtime.Host, null);
   Console.WriteLine("name: " + vm.Name + " >>lives on>> " + host.Name);
}
```

Basically I had to pass the MOR to client.GetView(**MOR**, null) and I found myself with a fresh managed object for the associated host or vm, depending on the perspective.